# Initializing a variable with a nested dictionary literal

Tags: python

I get unsorted plain list of subsubobjects from a database (CoachDb) and I want to sort the objects in an object tree using dictionaries.

My Object tree looks like this:

```
object.subobject.subsubobject
```

Each object type has an Id unique within the object level.
My idea was to get the ids from the document and insert the object in the object tree:

```
oid = doc.getId("object")
soid = doc.getId("subobject")
ssoid = doc.getId("subsubobject")

objtree[oid][soid][ssoid] = doc
```

Would it work?
If yes, how should I initialize objtree variable for using such nested indexing?

I've tried

```
objtree = {{{}}}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> objtree = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
>>> objtree[1][2][3] = 1
>>> objtree
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x99a0ed4>,
            {1: defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {2: {3: 1}})})
>>> objtree[1][2][3]
1
```